# Add button control in current cell of datagrid view control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to add a custom control(Button) in current cell of Datagridview 
    control. i have created the custom control(Button). My requirement is  when i 
    clicking any cell of the Datagridview, this control should show on that cell. 
    here is the screen shot of this.

[image]

Please help me to overcome this problem. Any help appreciated.

**NOTE:- This button is not a drop down button. It is just a simple button with drop down image. By clicking on this button a popup window will be open.**

Comment: Thanx @soner for editing my question now it looks much better.

Comment: If this button should open a drop down where the user can choose a value you should consider the [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No this button is a normal button with drop down image on it and it will open a popup window.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "when i clicking any cell of the Datagridview, this control should show on that cell.".
Add this button to each row added to the datagrid.

Comment: @etaiso: He surely means that the popup should be shown just like the dropdownmenu beneath the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need 1 button, set its `Parent` to your `DataGridView` and update its location according to the current cell bounds. This should be done in the `CellPainting` event handler, like this:

```
Button button = new Button(){Width = 20, Height = 20};
int maxHeight = 20;
button.Parent = dataGridView1;//place this in your form constructor
//CellPainting event handler for both your grids
private void dataGridViews_CellPainting(object sender,
                                        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) {
  DataGridView grid = sender as DataGridView;
  if (grid.CurrentCell.RowIndex == e.RowIndex &&
      grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex) {
     button.Top = e.CellBounds.Top - 2;
     button.Left = e.CellBounds.Right - button.Width;
     button.Height = Math.Min(e.CellBounds.Height, maxHeight);
     button.Invalidate();
  }
}
//Enter event handler for both your grids
private void dataGridViews_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
  button.Parent = (sender as Control);
}
```

**NOTE**: the `CellPainting` event handler (used for both grids) above should do something with the `button` only, if you add some other code such as for painting, both the grids will be effected by that code.

Comment: HI @King King, You have resolved my problem. Thanx alot and your help really appreciated.

Comment: Can we add this button for two grid. Actually i have 2 parallel grids with one scroll bar as separator between them.                  (Grid1-ScrollBar-Grid2). so this is looking like on grid. So can we do same for both of grids.

Comment: @TikamSangwani do you mean each grid has its own button (so we need 2 buttons) or both use the same button?

Comment: my requirement is both grid use the same button.

Comment: @TikamSangwani see my update, you need to register the `CellPainting` event handler for both grids.